# Drupal 7 - repication breaks with "Error 'Can't create database "

Tags: views

we are having replication issues (we are on Drupal 7, have 2 masters and 1 slave). Several times a week and sometimes a day replicaton breaks. This happens when we drop a database and then create it (creating new sites basically). We see the following errors in the logs:

> [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Can't create database 'cmssite3gwuedu';
>   database exists' on query. Default database: 'cmssite3gwuedu'. Query:
>   'CREATE DATABASE `cmssite3gwuedu`', Error_code: 1007

And then replicaton breaks. At this point we have 99 databases and will have more. Moreover, these databases are created by Aegir tool. I understand that these types of issues are cased by replicating everything - temp data, cache, etc and that those should be omitted from replicaton. The solution that I found is to basically specify the database that you wand and do not want to replicate and ignore cache, watchdog and temp tables. Like this:

```
binlog-do-db=<strong>DrupalDB
</strong>   # A database you do NOT want to replicate
binlog-ignore-db=DontReplicateThisDB
   # Don't replicate the "mysql" database itself (i.e., local MySQL config)
binlog-ignore-db=mysql
server-id=1
sync_binlog=1
#Minimizes the number of changes you lose if a problem occurs down to 1, reference
#max_allowed_packet = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
#
   # Don't replicate Drupal cache, watchdog, temporary search data
replicate-wild-ignore-table=DrupalDB%.cache%
replicate-wild-ignore-table=DrupalDB%.watchdog%
replicate-ignore-table=DrupalDB.temp_search_sids
replicate-ignore-table=DrupalDB.temp_search_results
```

The problem with this solution is that we have 99 databases and more will be created later. Do we have to specify all 99 in replicate-wild-ignore? Will this work? Has anyone faced the same issue (having multiple databases). I understand that mysql database should not be replicated. Thank you for any input!